# How to remove the header from a file only if exist in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have this sample file. I want to remove the first line (header) of this file only when it (header) exist using bash.

```
id name job_id
1 john 25
2 adam 45
3 paul 75
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in one operation with `sed` using the `-i` option (assuming your version of `sed` supports it — not all do).  For example:

```
sed -i.bak -e '1{/^id name job_id/d;}' file
```

This takes line 1 of the file and applies the commands in the braces to it.  The braces search for the pattern shown and delete the line.  If the first line doesn't match, it isn't deleted.  Other lines are left untouched.

The semicolon and backup suffix are necessary with Mac OS X `sed`; with GNU `sed`, you could omit either or both.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use awk to do this :

```
awk 'NR!=1||$0!="id name job_id" {print $0}' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filename='myfile'
[[ $(head -n 1 -- "$filename") == 'id name job_id' ]] && sed -i '1d' -- "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if head -1 original.txt | grep -Fxq 'id name job_id'
then tail -n+2 original.txt > newdoc.txt
fi
```

EDIT: Only checks first line and prints rest in a new file if the header exists. If not, the original is unchanged.

Comment: Doesn't that delete any lines after the first that contain the pattern too?

Comment: I tried it out in bash (and again after your comment), but it seems to work okay. My answer is hasty in the sense that it doesn't take just the first line, which I should have done, but I'm almost certain it basically gets the job done.

Comment: If the header isn't repeated in the body of the file, your commands are OK; if the header is repeated, you eliminate the repeats too, which isn't strictly what the question asked for.  There's an answer using `sed` with (currently) 2 down-votes that suffers from the same problem.  Arguably, you should have a `-x` in the filtering command (and maybe rename the temporary file back to the original too).

Comment: Oh, I think I misread your original comment for some reason. Yeah, it would do that. I'll fix it.

Answer (score -3):

```
sed '/id name job_id/d' fileName
```

Comment: This is going to delete it even if it is not the first line.

Comment: Yes, this answer is incorrect, please delete it. While it will *probably* work, the solution shouldn't make assumptions about the contents of the file, and having this as an answer may mislead future visitors. Also, there's already a correct answer using sed.